# extra margin space in div

Tags: html, css

I'm just starting out with HTML & CSS. In the snippet below I am trying to add a div. In chrome there are extra margins which takes up the entire width of the page, which I don't want. I tried making it 0, but still the margins don't go away.

```css
#row4div {
  clear: both;
  width: 100px;
  margin-top: 60px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="row4div">
  <span id="row4">
    <label> Degree : </label>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Postings here have a feature where CSS and HTML code can be run within the display using a code snippet. I have put this in your question to permit people to see how your code works and experiment with it. You can improve the wording of your question further by clicking the [edit] button if you wish.

Comment: @BrianTompsett-汤莱恩 accidentally deleted my old comment; the OP's formatting was atrocious, to say the least, so any improvement was good. OP: please read the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to learn how to ask a proper question/how to properly format your question.

Answer (score 2):

Browser by default adds some margin to the body element. You need to add margin: 0 to the body element.

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#row4div {
  clear: both;
  width: 100px;
  margin-top: 60px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="row4div">
  <span id="row4">
    <label> Degree : </label>
  </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure this has to do with how the code is handled in webkit.
This happens in Chrome and Safari, but not in Firefox.

If you add

```
float: left;
```

to your div this margin on the right disappears.
This way you can position other elements next to it if you want to by giving the next element

```
float: left;
```

```css
#row4div {
    /* clear: both; */
    width: 100px;
    margin-top: 60px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="row4div"> 
    <span id="row4">
        <label>Degree :</label>
    </span>
</div>
```